# Can i send a instagram DM via zapier from the data collected from google sheet?

Tags: instagram, google-sheets-api, zapier, typeform

I have connected zapier to collect user ID and message to be sent from TypeForms to Google Sheet, next is the process of using the user id from GOOGLE sheet to Instagram through zapier. how do i do that?

I have tried hell a lot of ways but nothing worked out

If u have a entire alternative way of getting Instagram id and the  message to be sent from the user and to send THAT SHIT to Instagram, please suggest me

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [Zapier page for Instagram](https://zapier.com/apps/instagram/integrations) does not look like there is any action to "send a DM".

But they do have a way to make an API request to Instagram API.

Looking at the [Instagram API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference), it is not possible via the API.

If it's not possible via a public API, you will unlikely be able to achieve this.

Comment: thx man, can you also tell me how u can trigger python script automatically when my google sheet is updated?

Comment: I think you can have trigger: sheet update, action code by Zapier. You can pick Python.
here you can read more https://zapier.com/blog/code-by-zapier-guide/

If the answer is correct you should accept it.